# Avoid repeating a verb in a sentence: "includes [category] including…"

Tags: word-choice, phrases

I'm not a native English speaker, so forgive me in advance if the question sounds very simple.

In one of the sentences of my application letter I want to say:

> My professional experience includes a full spectrum of technologies including:
> - ...
> - ...

Here I'm using "include" twice, which of course should be avoided.
I'm not even sure "include" is the correct word for any of the two spots where it's used.

I was thinking about alternatives such as:

> - My professional experience includes a full spectrum of technologies, to name a few:
> - My professional experience involves a full spectrum of technologies including:

But I'm not really happy about any of those options.
How should I phrase this sentence so it avoids repeating words and looks professional?

Comment: Either of your suggestions seem fine. Or you could say "My experience includes a full spectrum of technologies, encompassing..."

Comment: Just use ***consists of*** or ***covers*** or similar for the first instance. Note that ***involves*** is not a "happy" verb for the context, imho.

Comment: Or **encompasses** if you want a really fancy word.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using ***such as*** or ***among which***. Then you use only one verb and successfully avoid any repetition:

> My professional experience includes a full spectrum of technologies ***such as/among which***

***Such as*** is

> used to introduce an example or series of examples ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/such%20as))

Answer (score -2):

My professional experience includes a full spectrum of following technologies :-

I hope this sentence is satisfying for you.

Comment: This is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: Perhaps, it might just be better to write: "I have professional experience in the following technologies: (now include your list). Maybe you wouldn't even need to include "the following technologies." "I have professional experience in (add list)."